# clientWidth returing incorrect width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have set the width of an image (img tag) to 1150px

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    user-select: none;
}
#background-image-myos {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 1150px;
}
```

However, clientHeight is returning 1146

```
alert("Height is " + document.getElementById("background-image-myos").clientHeight);
alert("Width is " + document.getElementById("background-image-myos").clientWidth);
```

Why? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`, which takes into account borders, padding etc,.

Like so:

```
alert("Height is " + document.getElementById("background-image-myos").offsetHeight);
alert("Width is " + document.getElementById("background-image-myos").offsetWidth);
```